# How to read USB HID Report Descriptor on Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, usb, hid

Assuming that I have other information about HID device like `Device Descriptor`, `Configuration Descriptor` and `Interface Descriptor` how can I read `Report Descriptor`? Is there any WinAPI function to get this info in usermode?

If this help somehow: I found [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52106252/how-to-request-usb-hid-report-descriptor-from-hid-devices-using-usbdeviceconnect) but regarding Android Host. I humbly assume that having WinAPI equivalent of `UsbDeviceConnection.controlTransfer()` function will answer my question.